# Focusing new window after building (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have started writing an app using JavaFX (the open one) for GUI. I'm having this issue which is really annoying me. When I compile my app the window would appear in the background.

What I want is that when I compile my app and it would show I would have focus on that new window.

My OS is openSUSE Leap 15.1, Plasma desktop.

And here's my Main code in case it could matters:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("forms/login/FrmLogin.fxml"));
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
        primaryStage.toFront();
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to open a ticket with your OS, that JavaFX code looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't even thought about that it can be an issue. I tested my project on Windows and then on previous version of openSUSE and it worked as expected. Aside of OS version the other difference was that I used "portable" version of Intellij IDEA instead of flatpak one and turned out that the flatpak is the issue, perhaps it doesn't have necessary privilages to focus new window.

Comment: Did you find out what caused the issue @FilipK? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Joschua Nope, I'm just starting it with jetbrains toolbox. Then there's no problem

Comment: @FilipK Thanks. Very odd issue..

Answer (score 1):

As described in comments to original post:

I tested my project on Windows and then on previous version of openSUSE and it worked as expected. Aside of OS version the other difference was that I used "portable" version of Intellij IDEA instead of flatpak one and turned out that the flatpak is the issue, perhaps it doesn't have necessary privilages to focus new window